# Enable .htaccess in ubuntu ngnix server for php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-14.04

My Current .htaccess File Like :

```
RewriteEngine on  
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9/]+)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now it does not support Ubuntu 14.04 ngnix server. I want a URL pattern like:

> abc.com/user/1

How can I achieve that?

Comment: please [check this](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your nginx config, nginx server not reading .htaccess files

```
location / { rewrite ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9/]+)/?$ /index.php?q=$1 break; }
```